# Resolve Node.js crypto module in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, cryptojs, react-native-hermes

I have React Native project, where I installed a npm package, which used itself `crypto` module of node (`require('crypto')`) and it causing issues with React Native. is there any modern / clean way to somehow resolve this part, and use React Native compatible library, where node crypto is "required"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rn-nodeify` package which allow you to use node core modules in  your React Native app.

```
npm install rn-nodeify
```

install specific shims and hack

```
rn-nodeify --install "fs,dgram,process,path,console" --hack
```

It is recommended to add this command to the "postinstall" script in your project's package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install fs,dgram,process,path,console --hack"
}
```

rn-nodeify will create a shim.js file in your project root directory. The first line in index.ios.js / index.android.js should be to import it (NOT require it!)

```
import './shim'
```

**Example**

```
// index.ios.js or index.android.js
// make sure you use `import` and not `require`!
import './shim.js'
// ...the rest of your code
import crypto from 'crypto'
// use crypto
console.log(crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex'))
```

for more details [Visit nodeify package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify)

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that, one of the npm packages uses `require('crypto')`, and that's causing problem

Comment: could you share which npm package required `crypto`?
one suggestion: you can use same package and can change accordingly in node-module of that package which required crypto and make its patch.