# Jsonwebtoken - JWT, is not working on my react Native project

Tags: react-native, jwt

I am using `jwt` to decode my token to check if it is expired or not, I get an error on crypto module not found.

```js
    import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
    
    const checkToken = token => { 
       try { 
           const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token); 
           const experiationTime = decodedToken.exp;
           const expirationDate = new Date(experiationTime * 1000);
    
           if (expirationDate > currentDate) {
              console.log('Token is still valid', expirationDate);
              return true;
            } else {
              console.log('Token is expired', expirationDate);
              return false;
            }
         }
       catch(err){
           console.log(err)
       }
     }
```

**I get the followin error**

> Unable to resolve module crypto from <app_Name>\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js: crypto could not be found within the project or in these directories:
> node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules
> node_modules
> 7 | const PS_SUPPORTED = require('./lib/psSupported');
> 8 | const jws = require('jws');
> 9 | const {KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPublicKey} = require("crypto");

Since React-Native does not use the Node runtime environment and thus does not have access to specific libraries such as `crypto'`, so I installed `nodeify` & in `package.json` I include the below statement

1. npx rn-nodeify --install
2. script:{
   ...
   "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install crypto,assert,url,stream,events --hack"
   }

But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can import `import './shim.js'` before `const {KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPublicKey} = require("crypto");` and patch it.

you can check this to how can configure it:
[Resolve Node.js crypto module in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087224/resolve-node-js-crypto-module-in-react-native/78087440?noredirect=1#comment137674194_78087440)

Answer (score 0):

Try jwt-decode package available in npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode here you can get

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).